# data type should be anything inside module typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to have a datatype, instead of `any` , which is part of a module like this:

```
module SomeModule  {
    export class One  { 
        // ...
    }

    export class Two { 
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I need something like this:

```
function bla(myModel: anyThingInsideModule_insteadOfAnyDataType){...}
```

Is That possible ?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can have them implement/extend a base interface/class:

```
module SomeModule {
    export interface Base { }

    export class One implements Base { }

    export class Two implements Base { }
}

function bla(myModel: SomeModule.Base) { }
```

Or:

```
module SomeModule {
    export abstract class Base { }

    export class One extends Base { }

    export class Two extends Base { }
}
```

You can also make the function generic:

```
function bla<T extends SomeModule.Base>(myModel: T) { }
```

Comment: what about bla(myModel: One | Two) ? that way there's no need to extend or implement anything.

Comment: That will require to change the function signature every time a new class is added or removed. If you extend/implements a common type then you can safely remove/add classes without the need to change the function

Comment: true but in that case you have to make sure every class implements or extends the base. In both cases you need to manage that somehow. If they have common functionality or behaviour that would be fine if not.. having a marker interface just for this seems a bit much. :) Also it would be easier to make a Type that includes only the classes you want. That way everything is centralized and it doesn't require a class hierarchy. :)

Comment: @toskv You can create a type alias which is a union of all the module classes, but again, you'll need to manage that when classes are added/removed/renamed. As for having a common parent, there's nothing to manage if your base class only means "member of this module".  But if a function is expecting all of those classes then they probably have something in common anyway...

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript 2.0, you can specify multiple possible data types for a parameter or even a variable:

```
function bla (myModel: One | Two)
```

Then you can use parameters of either type.

**EDIT**
In the case that SomeModel is very large, as written in the comment below (apparently 100+ classes, which I think is bad design but hey, I'm not judging), it would probably be easiest to just create an `abstract` base class in `SomeModel` and have every class in the model derive from that.

```
export abstract class MyModelClass { /* Any shared logic here */ }

export class One extends MyModelClass { ... }

export class Two extends MyModelClass { ... }

...
```

Then you can write

```
function bla(myModel: MyModelClass) { ... }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but `SomeModel` has more than 100 classes.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that.